# Help, my robot is naked!

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Where can I find gear for C2-N2? Is there any point? So far it seems like he just sits around in my ship making annoying comments and helps w/ Crew Skill Missions. Is there gear that can help him do missions better? If nothing else can I get stuff to make him look cooler? Is it too much to hope for a chip that will give  him a less annoying personality?

Comment: While these answers regarding the ship droid are all accurate, it should be noted that the Trooper, Jedi Knight, and Imperial Agent all have other Droid companions which can use Droid Parts and are... much more useful than the shipdroid.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because droid parts were removed with Patch 4.0.  C2-N2, like all other droid companions, now only has a Weapon slot.  Note also that all companion gear is now purely for looks, so even humanoid biological companions do not need armor to help them perform.

Comment: Voting to leave open as per [What should be done with out of version questions?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5727/4797) and [What do we do with historic questions that no longer make sense?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7235/4797)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your ship's droid companion uses standard droid parts (produced by Cybertechs, bought for commendations, or found as quest rewards), but no parts will help him succeed at missions - affection is the only thing that can affect missions.

Just use him for gathering missions, and phase him out as you get the rest of your companions — **anything he can do, your other companions can do better.**

Answer (score 6):

As Raven Dreamer noted, you need droid parts to make him companion ready. And why would you use this incredibly annoying heap of scrap on your missions? Because he's the only healer pet you get at early levels unless you are the bounty hunter. You can equip him on the cheap if you always select the droid parts on the companion gear rewards for the first few you do.  (Companion gear normally shows up as the rewards for the any of the non-main story line, planetary or class)

The companion system is set up so you will mostly have one less deployable slot than you have companions. This means that you should always have a free companion to run around with, although if you spend a lot of time in a group that won't matter much. Which puts the question of which companion should be allowed to see the world while you work the others like little third world children in your own personal sweat shop? Since affection controls both the time it takes to run a crew skill mission AND how often you get a critical success on crafting, any hardcore crafter should outfit the droid and max out the affection of the others ASAP! Assuming you put in 160 hours getting to fifty having your maxed out affection nets you around 43 "bonus hours" on your crew skills... which means more purples, materials and every thing else that you use to make MONEY. (The math there is based on the Bounty hunter companion gains... I know the trooper gets even more as they get their companions earlier than the bounty hunter does.)

If you aren't a crafter? That droid sucks... kick his crappy ass to the curb and only think about him when your cursing the fact the Bioware chose to put him right at the door to your ship so you have to listen to his sniveling voice every time you come aboard.

Comment: Ship Droid can also be used for [settling scores.](http://i.imgur.com/D3UKtl.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read at the [Wiki:](http://www.wikiswtor.com/C2-N2)

C2-N2 can eventually be summoned to aid in combat, but in order for him to be any better in combat, you'd have to make parts for him with Cybertech, or purchase droid parts from the Galactic Trade center.